# Google Compute Engine: Possible to capture an image with multiple disks?

Tags: image, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm coming from Azure and am new to Google Cloud. Currently I see no way of capturing an image with more than 1 disks; only 1 bootable disk is allowed per image. I may be able to work around this by creating an instance template and attaching a disk but that disk will be read-only and must be in the same region as the instance.  Is there an easy way to package a VM with a boot disk and a data disk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible. Below *command* create image for the whole instance (all disks)

```
gcloud beta compute machine-images create instance-image ....
```

Detail can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/compute/machine-images/create).

P/s: It's different from the below command which create image for one disk only

```
gcloud compute images create ....
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to find a way to do this either as images and snapshots are disk based. As you stated you could create a template and attach a disk, although the disk has to be previously created, therefore, is almost as a manual procedure. All I could think of would be using a script to create a [disk](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/disks/create) and then create the [template](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instance-templates/create) or [instance](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create) directly using that disk with the flag --local-ssd.

Answer (score 0):

So I posted the same question on Reddit and got a response from someone who seems to work there.  The only current way is to create a disk using a snapshot and attached it to the instance when you're making it.  I was able to automate this with a YAML file but the huge drawback is the slow deployment (has to create the disks first before creating the instance).  Here's what he said about the matter:

"... there is a feature that they are testing in Alpha right now that does what you want. it should go live Q2 this year. So it's just a matter of time."